# Proving the a set $L \subset \mathbb{N}$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

here's a question I have for homework:

> We have seen already the $\mathbb{R}$ is an archimedean field, meaning
>   that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if 
>   $L \subset \mathbb{N}$ is infinite it is also not bounded in
>   $\mathbb{R}$.

So, here's what I did and I just want to make sure I'm right:

Suppose by contradiction that $L$ is bounded. We know that in a complete ordered field every non-empty set that is bounded from above has a supremum, meaning:
$$\forall x \in L:x \le sup(L)$$
But $(x+1)\in L$ and therefore we get 
$$\forall x \in L:x \le sup(L)-1$$
Contradicting the face that $sup(L)$ is the lowest upper bound.
Proving that there's no lower bound is similar.

Here's my problem: I don't know the elements of $L$, only that $L$ is infinite. 
So even if $x+1$ is not in $L$, I know that ther'e another number that is in $L$ and is greater then $x$.

Two questions:

1. Was I right about what I wrote?
2. How do I formally define an element in $L$ that is greater then $x$, when I don't have the definition of $L$?

Thanks!

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is an ordered field in which sets bounded above do not necessarily have suprema. What you’re using there is the fact that the reals are **completely** ordered.

Comment: Changed it to complete ordered field

Comment: You cannot automatically claim that $\sup (L)$ (if it exists) is an element of $L$ (you would have to make a further argument that this would be true).  (As for your second question, recall that the set of natural numbers has [a very nice property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle).)

Comment: I don't think I claimed anywhere the $sup(L) \in L$, did I?

Comment: @yotamoo: My apologies, I seem to have misread/read too quickly.  Upon a closer inspection (where's my brain today?) no, you don't assume that $\sup (L) \in L$.  You do assume that $x \in L \rightarrow x+1 \in L$, which would imply that (assuming $L \neq \emptyset$) $L$ is a final segment of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Suppose that  $L\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then, there exists $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\leq y$ for all $x\in L$.  Let $n=\lceil y \rceil$ (where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ denotes the [ceiling function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).  Then $L\subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ (**why?**), and hence $L$ is finite.